# Find the length of subarray of minimal length consisting of all the elements

Tags: algorithm

Given an integer N
and an array of length N consisting of integers from 0 to N-1
may or may not contain all the integers and may contain duplicates.
Find a subarray (i,j) from index i to index j such that it contains all the
integers that are in the array and is of minimum length. The output is the length of such
a subarry
**Example:** A=[2,1,1,3,2,1,1,3] so minimal subarray length =3 as A[2] to A[4] contains all the numbers
**My Thoughts:**
Maintain a counter array and two index start and end which contains a count of elements
from the start to end index of the array.
Iterate over the array each time updating the value of the counter
and setting the end to the current index
and incrementing start till counter[start]>1. Initially start=0, end=0

This approach seems logically correct to me. I encountered this problem during a programming test and did pass all the sample test cases. But it failed all the hidden cases. I may be missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

Parse the array once to count its distinct members.

Next, use 2 pointers. Keep a counting map of value counts between the pointers, and also keep track of the number of distinct elements between the pointers.

Any time the number of distinct elements  between the pointers is too small, advance the forward pointer, o/w the rear pointer.

Keep track of and return the smallest distance between pointers that has the full count of distinct elts.

Comment: Exactly. We can also say that we can adopt sliding window technique.

Answer (score 0):

first find number of distinct elements and then apply sliding window.

looks similiar to https://leetcode.com/problems/subarrays-with-k-different-integers/